# Finding craters [descending/ ascending ints] in a python list of ints

Tags: python, list, int

I have a list of ints in python, and I would like the output to be a list of different "craters" in the sequence. I define a crater as a sequence of numbers that begins with descending ints that gradually grow bigger, until they reach a number that is equal to the first int of the crater or greater than the first int in the crater. 
If the last number is equal or smaller than the first - it should be in the output at the end of the crater. If the last number is greater than the first number in the crater - it should not be appended to the end of the output list.

For example, for the list: 
1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
A "crater" would be:
6,5,4,3,4,5,6

My code:

```
def find_crater(my_list):
cur_crater = []
for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
    #check if the numbers are decreasing
    if (my_list[i] - my_list[i+1] > 0):
        cur_crater.append(my_list[i])
    #if increasing - check if we're in a crater 
    #and if current number is smaller than begining of crater
    elif len(cur_crater) > 1 and my_list[i] <= cur_crater[0]:
        cur_crater.append(my_list[i])
    #print crater and empty list 
    elif len(cur_crater) > 1 and my_list[i+1] > cur_crater[0]:
        print(cur_crater)
        cur_crater = []
    #continue if we're out of a crater
    else:
        continue
#catching the last crater in the list
if len(cur_crater) > 1:
    #include last int
    if my_list[i] - my_list[-1] < 0  and my_list[-1] <= cur_crater[0]:
        cur_crater.append(my_list[-1])
    print(cur_crater)
return
```

I have called the function on 2 lists. The 1st output is as expected:

```
ok_list = [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23, 
24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14,
17, 27, 28, 19, 17, 19, 21, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]
```

Ok list output [edit: not so ok - it ommited the first '4' so turns out it's not so OK after all]:

```
[12, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12]
[26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17]
[28, 19, 17, 19, 21, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]
```

However, the second list combines 2 lists of craters into 1 list in the output:

```
problematic = [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23, 
24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 
17, 27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]
```

problematic Output:

```
[12, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12]
[26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17, 27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25]
```

I was expecting:

```
[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12]
[26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17]
[27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]
```

I tried to take care of this by writing: 
my_list[i+1] > cur_crater[0]
and thus checking the size of next int in the list - but that does not seem to fix it [I left it in the code even though it does not do the trick in hopes of someone explaining why is that wrong/ not working?].

In conclusion, my code can't handle it when there is a crater right after a crater with only one int in between.

If the input is:

[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10]

Then the output is one long list, but I'd like to split it after list item 12 and before list item 21, but the output is one long list.

I would love to get info about any library or method that can give me more ideas regarding a better and more efficient solution.

Comment: why you are ok with second list output `[26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17]` as per your expectation it should have stopped at `28` i.e. either equal to the first int or greater?

Comment: I meant if it's equal/smaller - It belongs in the solution.I'll rewrite my question. I guess it's not clear, my bad

Comment: include the output you are expecting for `[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10]`

Comment: ok I get it, if the number is greater it isn't included in the output.

Comment: Yep. Sorry if my phrasing wasn't great...

Comment: have you used numpy before - it should be much quicker providing you can create a vectorised form of your algorithm

Comment: Thanks @seanv507  I've used Numpy on a very small scale for specific parts of my coding problems. I'll look into it. Numpy will definitely be included in my next attempt for solving this.

Comment: Why is the first 4 missing, it descends from 12 > 4 then goes up to 7?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that, thanks.Turns out it's not OK at all. I'll remove it  from the question... or edit it it. Sorry. Guess there is a lot more work on this. I may seek for Numpy help and discard this solution altogether... Thanks again

Comment: @hakabuk please gave a stare at my answer that might help you

Comment: So it should be `[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12]` or `[12, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12]`?

Comment: @hakabuk, your accepted answer does not follow your logic

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it should be [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12]

Comment: Try `[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23, 24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17, 27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27, 12,3,4]`, according to your specs 27 should be added to the second last list and a new one created after

Comment: Based on number equal to the first being added, the start of a chain beginning with a descending number the correct output is `[[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12], [26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17], [27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27], [12, 3, 4]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming your expected output is wrong which it seems to be, all you want to do is go until you find an element >= to the start of the chain and catch chains that only contain a single element:

```
def craters(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    # get start of first chain
    first = next(it)
    tmp = [first]
    # iterate over the remaining
    for ele in it:
        # >= ends chain
        if ele >= first:
            # if equal, add it and call
            #  next(it) to set the next first element.
            if ele == first:
                tmp.append(ele)
                yield tmp
                first = next(it)
                tmp = [first]
            # else yield the group if it has > 1 element.
            # if it has 1 element it is not a descending start sequecne
            else:
                if len(tmp) > 1:
                    yield tmp
                tmp = [ele]
                first = ele
        else:
            tmp.append(ele)
     if len(tmp) > 1: # catch single element last
         yield tmp
```

Output:

```
In [5]: ok_list = [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23,
   ...:            24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14,
   ...:            17, 27, 28, 19, 17, 19, 21, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]

In [6]: problematic = [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23,
   ...: 24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14,
   ...: 17, 27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]

In [7]: ex_ok = [[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12],
   ...: [26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17],
   ...: [28, 19, 17, 19, 21, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]]

In [8]: ex_p = [[12,4,  7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12],
   ...: [26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17],
   ...: [27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]]

In [9]: print(list(craters(problematic)) == ex_p)
True

In [10]: print(list(craters(ok_list)) == ex_ok)
True

In [11]: print(list(craters([12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10])))
[[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12], [21, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10]]
In [12]: list(craters([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
Out[13]: [[6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

That does not involve any slicing/indexing you can lazily return each group.

To simplify your algorithm, the steps are:

- Start with the first element, then check if the next element is >=, if it is and it is equal add it to the group, if it is > set that to be the new *start* of the group.
- If the new first is not greater than  the next element the length of that group will be one as it does not satisfy *sequence of numbers that begins with descending*. So we keep consuming and setting the next element to be the *first* element of the sequence until we find one the is > the next element,  that is what the call to `next(it)` is doing then we just need to wash and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came with:

```
def find_crater(my_list):
    previous = None
    current_crater = []
    crater_list = []
    for elem in my_list:

        #For the first element
        if not previous:
            previous = elem
            continue

        if len(current_crater) == 0:
            if elem > previous:
                previous = elem
            else:
                current_crater.append(previous)
                previous = elem
        else:
            if elem > current_crater[0]:
                current_crater.append(previous)
                crater_list.append(current_crater)
                current_crater = []
                previous = elem
            else:
                current_crater.append(previous)
                previous = elem

    if len(current_crater) != 0:
        if elem > current_crater[0]:
            current_crater.append(previous)
            crater_list.append(current_crater)
        else:
            current_crater.append(previous)
            crater_list.append(current_crater)

    return crater_list
```

That gave me the exact output you want:

```
In [5]: ok_list = [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23, 
   ...: 24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14,
   ...: 17, 27, 28, 19, 17, 19, 21, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]

In [6]: find_crater(ok_list)
Out[6]: 
[[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12],
 [26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17],
 [28, 19, 17, 19, 21, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]]

In [7]: problematic = [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23, 
   ...: 24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 
   ...: 17, 27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]

In [8]: find_crater(problematic)
Out[8]: 
[[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12],
 [26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17],
 [27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]]
```

Comment: Small issue of a duplicated 27 at the end. Will look into it. Thanks

Comment: @hakabuk, you are right, I've edited the code to remove the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

We just slice the list finding `start_index:end_index` making three cases

- When element is equal
- When element is greater
- Boundary case when last element even if smaller may need to be sliced

---

```
def find_crater(l):    
    result = []
    start_index = 0
    for i in range( start_index +1,len(l)):
        start = l[start_index]
        if i==len(l)-1 and l[i]!=start:
            result = l[start_index:i+1]
            print result
        elif l[i]==start:
            end_index = i+1
            result = l[start_index:end_index]
            start_index = end_index +1
            if len(result)>1:
                print result
        elif l[i]>start:
            end_index = i
            result = l[start_index:end_index]
            start_index = end_index 
            if len(result)>1:
                print result
```

**Input:**

```
ok_list = [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23, 
24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14,
17, 27, 28, 19, 17, 19, 21, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]

problematic = [12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23, 
24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 
17, 27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]
```

**Output:**

```
find_crater(ok_list)
find_crater(problematic)

[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12]
[25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17]
[28, 19, 17, 19, 21, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]

[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12]
[25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17]
[27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27]
```

Comment: This also fails according to the specs.

Comment: which one? give sample input/ouput

Comment: `[12, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 12, 21, 23, 24, 26, 25, 22, 10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 17, 27, 19, 25, 19, 12, 23, 25, 27, 12,3,4]`, where is 26 in your output from the second list? 26 -> 25 is desending, just like `26, 25, 22` is ok in the ok_list output of the OP's